# A question about connected inner limiting sets

Tags: gn.general-topology

Let M be a finite-dimensional Euclidean space or an infinite-dimensional separable Banach space.
An inner limiting subset of M is a countable intersection of open subsets of M-these sets are
usually called "G-delta" sets nowadays. Does every infinite connected inner limiting subset of M
contain an infinite connected proper subset H and a point p that is not a limit point of H?

Comment: A G-delta set of such spaces is precisely a completely metrisable separable metric space. 

Comment: In fact, the equivalent question in more modern terms: does every connected Polish space have a proper closed connected subspace ? 

Comment: Does this question have a known answer or is it an open problem?

Comment: This seems very closely related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25171/how-thinly-connected-can-a-closed-subset-of-hilbert-space-be

Comment: @BS: Looks equivalent, in fact.  This question should probably be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Garabed: to expand Henno's comment: recall that any $G_\delta$ of a separable $B$-space admits a topologically equivalent complete metric, so it is a Polish space; and that on the other hand by the Kuratowski embeddingm any complete metric space can be identified with a closed subset of a Banach space. Also, since the closure of a connected set is closed, you may assume $H$ closed. 

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer.

If M has a subset that is somewhere locally path-connected, then yes.  Otherwise, M is nowhere path connected, and this should put some interesting restrictions on M.  Even in this case I do not see where M could nontrivially avoid all tuples (p,O) where p is a point and O a basis element of the space that does not contain p in its closure.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2010.09.09